# How do I stream audio with Discord?

Tags: arch-linux, audio

When I use the "Go Live" feature on Discord, the other people in the channel say they can see the video output of what I stream, but cannot hear the audio.

How do I stream the video and source audio -- without audio from other sources -- thru Discord while also being able to use my microphone to talk with people in the chat?

Basically, how do I stream in Discord on Arch Linux so that things work the same way as they would in Windows?

Comment: Do you access Discord from a browser or from the Discord client app? I had issues streaming audio with the former but the latter worked.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I use pipewire. Install the packages `pipewire-jack pipewire-alsa pipewire-pulse qjackctl` (alsa and pulse may not be necessary but I have no proof to the contrary). These will replace the corresponding packages in your system. Then you can use `pw-jack qjackctl` to open qjackctl using pipewire's jack. You can then use the graph connector in qjackctl to connect your desktop audio to discord.